# files handling in C confusion (read a matrix from a file)

Tags: c, file, matrix

I am learning about file handling in C language and I'm pretty confused about something. Let's say I want to read a matrix from a file. Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void readMatrix(int n,int m,int a[][30],FILE *file1)
{
    
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        for(j=0;j<m;j++)
        {
            fscanf(file1,"%d",&a[i][j]);
        }
                    
    
}

void writeMatrix(int n,int m,int a[][30],FILE *file2)
{
    int i,j;    
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {   
        for(j=0;j<m;j++)
            fprintf(file2,"%d ",a[i][j]);
        
        fprintf(file2,"\n");
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n,m,a[30][30];
    FILE *file1, *file2;
    
    
    file1=fopen("file1.in","r");
    if(file1==0)
    {
        printf("Error!\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    file2=fopen("file2.out","w");   
    if(file2==0)
    {
        printf("Error!\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    
    fscanf(file1,"%d %d ",&n,&m);
    readMAtrix(n,m,a,file1);

    writeMAtrix(n,m,a,file2);

    fclose(fis1);
    fclose(fis2);
return 0;
}
```

If I compile this code I get the message "Error!" because I don't have a file1. I don't understand how the file1 is created.The "r" is come from reading from a file but how to create that file ? If I go to the location and I create with the mouse (with right click) a file, then the code works.

Another thing is that when I write "w" then file2 is created.I don't understand the difference between these 2 things. So, if I create file1 then I go in that file and I write n,m and the matrix then the matrix should appear in file2, right? But again, when I read, it creates nothing. I'm getting error. Can you help me?

Comment: `Error!` is *not* a useful error message.  Try `if( (file1 = fopen(path, mode)) == NULL ) { perror(path); exit(EXIT_FAILURE);}`  Write error messages to stderr and include a reason for the failure.

Comment: Check out: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fopen.htm

Comment: You can't read a book that is not in your bookshelf  but expect your PC to read a file that does not exist.

Comment: Probably `file1.in` does not exist, or the program is not looking in the directory where the file is. [Edit] the question and show more information: how do you run the program? Where is `file1.in`?

Comment: I know the file1 does not exist. My question was how to create this file? I create this file manually (by going to the program location -> left click -> new -> file.txt ) or there is another method from the program ?